# Layout com listview dúvidas

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou enfrentando um problema em layout, nesse layout tenho um ListView e depois do tenho mais 3 Buttons só que quando a lista é muito grande ela usa todo tamanho da tela e não consigo ver o Buttons, alguem pode me ajudar?

*Como está o layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtPesquisa"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lupa"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Pesquisa rápida"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,UnusedAttribute"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listDebitosPendentes"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        tools:ignore="NestedScrolling"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Enviar boleto por e-mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enviaBoletoEmail"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/enviar_linha_digit_vel_por_sms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enviaLinhaDigitavel" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/mostrar_linha_digit_vel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mostraLinhaDigitável" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione no `ListView` o peso `android:layout_weight="1"` desta forma o layout vai se reorganizar.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado.

Comment: Só uma pergunta, teria como eu adicionar esse peso pelo código java?

Comment: Acredito que tenha como sim, para fazer uma pesquisa como esta, vc pode pesquisar mais ou menos assim "layout_weight android programmatically" no google.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar um componente chamado ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/minha_tela_"> </include>
    </ScrollView>
```

Você basicamente vai ter dois xmls... um que representa o layout inteiro, e outro com esse componente. Na activity use setContentView nesse layout que tem o scrollview.
(Detalhe: nesse layout que tem o scrollview SÓ vai ter ele. Todo o resto vai estar no layout que chamei de "minha_tela")

Comment: Eu adicionei da forma que me falou, mas ficou estranho meu listView, ele só mostra um item por vez.

Comment: Na verdade é só setar o layout "pai" para match_parent...